# How to input and output item names, price, and quantity in a shopping cart?

Tags: c++, shopping-cart, accessor, mutators

I am trying to create a program that prompts user for item name, price, and quantity. And then outputs the info entered by the user. When I run it using inputs: Chocolate Chips, 3, 1, it outputs:

Item1

Enter the item name:

Chocolate

Enter the item price:

0

Enter the item quantity:

32599

It should be outputting:

Item1

Enter the item name:

Chocolate Chips

Enter the item price:

3

Enter the item quantity:

1

Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ItemToPurchase.h"

int main() {
  ItemToPurchase item1;
  ItemToPurchase item2;
  string name;
  int price;
  int quantity;

  cout << "Item 1" << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item name: " << endl; 
  cin >> name;
  item1.SetName(name);
  cout << item1.GetName() << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item price: " << endl;
  cin >> price;
  item1.SetPrice(price);
  cout << item1.GetPrice() << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item quantity: " << endl;
  cin >> quantity;
  item1.SetQuantity(quantity);
  cout << item1.GetQuantity() << endl;

  cin.ignore();

  cout << "Item 2" << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item name: " << endl; 
  cin >> name;
  item2.SetName(name);
  cout << item2.GetName() << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item price: " << endl;
  cin >> price;
  item2.SetPrice(price);
  cout << item2.GetPrice() << endl;
  cout << "Enter the item quantity: " << endl;
  cin >> quantity;
  item2.SetQuantity(quantity);
  cout << item2.GetQuantity() << endl;

 return 0;
 }
```

ItemToPurchase.h

```
#ifndef ITEM_TO_PURCHASE_H
#define ITEM_TO_PURCHASE_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ItemToPurchase {
   public:
      ItemToPurchase();
      void SetName(string name);
      void SetPrice(int price);
      void SetQuantity(int quantity);
      string GetName();
      int GetPrice();
      int GetQuantity();
  
   private:
      string itemName;
      int itemPrice;
      int itemQuantity;
   };



#endif
```

ItemToPurchase.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "ItemToPurchase.h"

   ItemToPurchase::ItemToPurchase() {  // Default constructor
     itemName = "none";         // Default name: none indicates name was not set
     itemPrice = 0;             // Default price: 0 indicates price was not set
     itemQuantity = 0;          // Default quantity: 0 indicates quantity was not set
  }

 // Accessors
 void ItemToPurchase::SetName(string name) {
    itemName = name;
 }

 void ItemToPurchase::SetPrice(int price) {
    itemPrice = price;  
 }

 void ItemToPurchase::SetQuantity(int quantity) {
    itemQuantity = quantity;  
 }

 // Mutators
 string ItemToPurchase::GetName() {
    return itemName;  
 }

 int ItemToPurchase::GetPrice() {
    return itemPrice;  
 }

 int ItemToPurchase::GetQuantity() {
    return itemQuantity;  
 }
```

Comment: standard input operator >> takes in input till it reaches whitespace (space or newline), not the whole line, which is why only chocolate can be seen. getline() can be used to obtain entire line instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
cin >> name;
```

with

```
getline (cin, name);
```

did the trick.